# Linear regression simulation

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, simulation

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this question.

I want to simulate $n$ datasets in R with eight predictors where $β=(3,1.5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0)$ and the pairwise correlation between $x_i$ and $x_j$ is set to be $\text{corr}(i,~j) = 0.5$ for $i-j$ or for all $i=j$.

Comment: What do you mean by "corr(i, j) = 0:5 for $i−j$ or for all $i=j$"?

Comment: There are 8 elements in your beta vector, do you want the intercept to be 0, or are you calling the intercept one of your 8 predictors?

Comment: Well, I mean that let the predictors be correlated at $p$=0.5. Thanks

Comment: Mr. gung,
Assume that $b$0=0.8 or whatever. Thank you so much

Comment: So, do you mean that ${\rm corr}(x_i, x_j) = 0.5$ for $i \neq j$, and one should drop the "$i = j$" part at the end of the sentence? Could you please amend the question to clarify the set-up?

Comment: I am sorry Mr.QuantIbex, ignore the $i≠j$ part.

Comment: Predictors with mutual correlations of $1/2$ are readily obtained as `matrix(rnorm(8*n), ncol=8) %*% chol(matrix(1/2, 8, 8) + diag(rep(1/2, 8)))`, but what role does "$\beta$" play?

Comment: Thank you so much dear whuber, well they are just arbitrary values for the coefficients.

Comment: Still not clear to me what the constraints on the predictors should be. It would help us help you if you could edit the question based on the clarifications you had to provide in the comments.

Comment: Amongst the 8 predictors, 5 have as coefficient equal to zero ($\beta_3 = \beta_4 = \beta_6 = \beta_7 = \beta_8 = 0$). So why do you want 8 predictors and not 3?

Comment: Well, Mr. QuantIbex, after that I am using Lasso and I want to know whether Lasso is picking the non-zero coefficients or not? I hope it would be clear. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
## Parameters
n     <- 20                         # number of samples
rho   <- 0.5                        # correlation between predictors
beta  <- c(0.8,3,1.5,0,0,2,0,0,0)   # regression coefficients
sigma <- 0.4                        # std error of noise (assumed Gaussian)
## Covariance matrix
d     <- length(beta)
Q     <- toeplitz(c(1, rep(rho, d - 2)))
## Design matrix
X <- cbind(1, matrix(rnorm((d-1) * n), ncol = d-1) %*% chol(Q))
## Dependent variable
Y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(n, 0, sigma)
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear Quantlbex. It is perfect, just one more question. When I fit lasso regression on it, I don't get 5 zero coefficients? Any idea?

Comment: I guess that increasing the penalty parameter of the Lasso model will eventually lead to zero coefficients. Further help will probably require further information on what you do and what you obtain.

Comment: Thank you so much. Eventually, I have reached the ideal solution and I fixed. Thank you very much indeed.